# Best way to store data from thread into global container?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a container that is meant to store some results. Say,

```
std::vector<double> allResults
```

and I have a bunch of threads working on getting these results, and storing them in the container. Each thread is tasked with getting multiple, but mutually distinct, results.

What is the best way to do this to avoid false sharing?

Is it okay to simply have one thread do its job on one result and then say

```
allResults[index] = //insert thread's result
```

since every thread is working on an index that no other thread will be sharing?

Or should I do something different, such as creating a separate vector for every thread:

```
std::vector<double> vectorForEachThread
```

and then each thread adds its result to this vector, and then when they are all done, combine these vectors in some way?

Comment: hard to respond in a general case, I guess it depends on the time each thread take to compute: if there is a lot of contention on the array, you may apply a different strategy than if the array is rarelly accessed (coputations are long and it is unlikely that threads tries to write at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

If the results are belonging to some inter-thread tasks, each task should return its own result to the requester thread with a message system, let's say a callback.

If the results show some sort of status, the parameter should be writable from just one object (or thread) and readable by many. These styles will save you from endless race condition debugging sessions.

If your structure could not accept such style, you can consider a refactor.

And finally, please avoid from global variables for such kind of tasks. Make them inter-thread messages.